# XMPP Server not connected with e-Jabberd - Always return "False"

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

i am working with XMPP framework and try to connect with server. I have tested with Adium. It connects fine but not working with code.
It always return Failed. can anyone guide me plz

```
func connect()
    {
        let stream = XMPPStream()
        stream?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

        stream?.hostName = "server.com"
        stream?.hostPort = 5222
        do
        {
            try stream?.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
        }
        catch
        {
            if stream?.isConnected()==true
            {
                print("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                print("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding by myJID like this stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.init(string: "XXXXXXXXXXX")

Answer (score 0):

`XMPPStream.connect` is *asynchronous* method and returns immediately.  Of course, it needs some time to connect, that is why you shouldn't check `isConnected` just after `connect`.

You need to implement `XMPPStreamDelegate` protocol and when stream will be connected it will "fire" `xmppStreamDidConnect:` "event", and this is the place where you can continue your connection logic

Comment: thnx. but i am the new one. can u plz help me little bit more by providing some piece of code.